# Optimize sqlite query and being able to compare object and database

Tags: c#, xml, database, sqlite

I'm developing a front end for retro gaming. Upon boot I'm parsing a lot of xml files from another application so I end up with a List of "systems" each containing a list of "games". Parsing the xml data is really fast, but writing all this to the sqlite database is not. Currently it takes ~25 seconds (20.000 records) which may not be too bad, but hopefully I can get some ideas on how to make it even faster.

Ideally I want to be able to compare my object containing all the data with the sqlite database. If anything has changed in the xml files/parsed object the data should be updated or deleted from the database. Is there a better way of solving this then doing a initial import and then dump all of the database and compare it to the object? Basically the whole import code backwards...

This is my current code:

```
public static void PopulateDatabase(List<RetroBoxSystem> systems)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=RetroBox.db;Version=3;"))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SQLiteTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    foreach (var system in systems)
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO systems(system_id, name)
                                            VALUES ((SELECT system_id FROM systems WHERE name = @name), @name)";

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@name", system.Name));
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO games(game_id, system_id, name, description, cloneof, manufacturer, genre, rating, year)
                                                VALUES ((SELECT game_id FROM games WHERE name = @name), (SELECT system_id FROM systems WHERE name = @system), @name, @description, @cloneof, @manufacturer, @genre, @rating, @year)";

                    foreach (var system in systems)
                    {
                        foreach (var g in system.GameList)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@system", system.Name));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@name", g.Name));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@description", g.Description));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cloneof", g.CloneOf));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@manufacturer", g.Manufacturer));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@genre", g.Genre));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@rating", g.Rating));
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@year", g.Year));
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }

                tr.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be the Entity Framework for comparing objects without coding everything yourself, however depending on your project type you might not have access to it (such as Windows Phone projects).

Your insert query seems pretty optimized, but maybe you can make it faster using async inserts with `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

More details about `ConfigureAwait` here: [How to massively improve SQLite Performance (using SqlWinRT)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/11/21/how-to-massively-improve-sqlite-performance-using-sqlwinrt.aspx)

Comment: Do the saving in background while the game is being played.  Using a better database will also improve performance.